# not showing figures in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

what is the reason for not showing the graphics inside a table,in the list of figures?I have used below code to insert figure inside a long table.

```
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./chapters/02/mcb.png}

\begin{center}
\refstepcounter{figure}% for proper numbering and referencing of figure and
 \small
 Figure~\thefigure:{Cabinet power distribution} box
 \end{center}
```

Answer (score 2):

The list of figures shows the figures included in a `figure` environment (more precisely: it lists the captions given within a figure environment).

All you do with `\refstepcounter{figure}` is increasing the number to be used for the next call to `\thefigure`; there's nothing in your code that tells Latex that there is a figure there, nor how to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

An example with the floating environment `figure` that comes with a `\caption` command that automatically adds the entry in the list of figures. The caption can be formatted with the help of package `caption`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{Cabinet power distribution box}
  \label{fig:cabinet}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]